# How to hash password with md5 instead of bcrypt in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-8, laravel-datatables

I want to hash password with md5 instead of bcrypt in laravel 8.
In my login controller LoginController.php :

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            return ['user_name' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => md5($request->password), 'actif' => 'Y'];
        }
```

And in my UserController I have:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {        
        $this->validationRules($request);        
        $user = new User();       
        $user->password = md5("00000000");
        $user->actif = 'Y';
        $user->user_name = $request->input('user_name');
        $user->save();

        return redirect('/users');
    }
```

The new user is saved in the database with md5 but when I try to login it gives me this error :

```
These credentials do not match with our records
```

Comment: I wonder since MD5 is now rather broken and unsafe, why would you insist on using it?

Answer (score 1):

after reading the resource code, your will find out that Laravel validate user's credentials in `vendor/src/Illuminate/src/Auth/EloquentUserProvider`

```php
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];
    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

1. So, first add a `getAuthPassword` function in your `Models/User.php`

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return ['password' => $this->attributes['password']];
    }
}
```

2. then, add a custom `SelfEloquentUserProvider` extends from `vendor/src/Illuminate/src/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php`

```php
namespace App\Libs;

use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class SelfEloquentUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
     * @param array $credentials
     */
    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];
        $authPassword = $user->getAuthPassword();
 
        return hash_equals(md5($plain), $authPassword['password']);
    }
}
```

3. then, register your `SelfEloquentUserProvider` in `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider`

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Auth::provider('self-eloquent', function ($app, $config) {
            return New \App\Libs\SelfEloquentUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
        });
    }
    ......
}
```

4. finally, in your `config/auth.php`

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'self-eloquent',
        'model' => \App\User::class,
    ]
]
```

you can custom your own auth rule easily by this way.

Comment: Ok, I will try this

Comment: It did not work when I dd('message') in validateCredentials() in EloquentUserProvider and in SelfEloquentUserProvider  it stil go to the validateCredentials() of EloquentUserProvider instead of SelfEloquentUserProvider.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the LOGIN controller.

In Laravel 7 with the AUTH package (*Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUser*s), you go to:

- Http > Controllers > Auth > LoginController.php

And you have to rewrite the trait AuthenticatesUsers with the method below:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    // Your login logic
}
```

If you use an other package, the method will be different, check in the documentation of your package if it's the case.